# Make ng-show trigger if input is focued

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I'm trying to show the Add button if the title is not empty or if the input is focused. In the following example the button shows if title is not empty, but I would like to also show the button if input is in focused.

```
<input ng-model="title" />
<button ng-show="title" ng-click="add(title)">Add</button>
```

Something like this is what i'm looking for but with input_is_focused replaced.

```
<input ng-model="title" />
<button ng-show="title || input_is_focused" ng-click="add(title)">Add</button>
```

One workaround could be to add ng-focus and ng-blur that calls a method that checks if title is empty and then show or hide the button, but that is not so clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just came up with an acceptable solution to my problem but is open for other suggestions that don't depend on `ng-focus` and `ng-blur`.

```
<input ng-model="title" ng-focus="focus=true" ng-blur="focus=false" />
<button ng-show="title || focus" ng-click="add(title)">Add</button>
```